# How to add a focus traversal with a different hotkey?

Tags: java, focus

I am having a problem implementing the last part of this program, which is to make it where pressing the Enter key moves the active field from one text field to the next one in order (1,2,3,4).

This needs to be done without removing the focus cycling that is used by the tab key.

I have no idea how to even begin doing that, the only thing I've found in the API is replacing the traversal policy with your own, but I don't want to replace it I want to create a new one that runs in parallel with the default one.

```
public class unit27 {

    JButton button1 = new JButton("add to next cup");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("add to next cup");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("add to next cup");
    JButton button4 = new JButton("add to next cup");

    JTextField text1 = new JTextField("4");
    JTextField text2 = new JTextField("4");
    JTextField text3 = new JTextField("4");
    JTextField text4 = new JTextField("4");

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Cup 1");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Cup 2");
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Cup 3");
    JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Cup 4");

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();

    public unit27() {

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 4));
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        panel3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        panel4.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        mainPanel.add(panel1);
        mainPanel.add(panel2);
        mainPanel.add(panel3);
        mainPanel.add(panel4);

        panel1.add(label1);
        panel1.add(button1);
        panel1.add(text1);

        panel2.add(label2);
        panel2.add(button2);
        panel2.add(text2);

        panel3.add(label3);
        panel3.add(button3);
        panel3.add(text3);

        panel4.add(label4);
        panel4.add(button4);
        panel4.add(text4);

        button1.add(text1);
        button1.addActionListener(new MyListener1());
        button2.addActionListener(new MyListener2());
        button3.addActionListener(new MyListener3());
        button4.addActionListener(new MyListener4());

        // end class

    }

    class MyListener1 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int a = Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText());

            int c = a + b;

            text2.setText(Integer.toString(c));

        }
    }

    class MyListener2 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int a = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(text3.getText());

            int c = a + b;

            text3.setText(Integer.toString(c));

        }
    }

    class MyListener3 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int a = Integer.parseInt(text3.getText());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(text4.getText());

            int c = a + b;

            text4.setText(Integer.toString(c));

        }
    }

    class MyListener4 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int a = Integer.parseInt(text4.getText());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());

            int c = a + b;

            text1.setText(Integer.toString(c));

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new unit27();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swing does not allow 2 focus cycles to be run at the same time. If you really need to have a second focus cycle (and not just add enter to the focus traversal keys), then what you could do is:

Create a Map which determines your cycle.
On each component with the extra cycle add a key binding for Enter that gets the next visible field in your cycle and calls requestFocus on it.

You would have to maintain the map and create custom checks to see if the next component is visible or should be skipped.